# Transferir dados para outro form c#

Tags: c#

Estou com a seguinte situação, tenho um formulário de pesquisa que tem os dados de pesquisa já carregados em um datatable como no trecho do código a seguir:

```
DataView dv = new DataView(dtTodosCampos);

string sVlrBusca = TextPesquisa.Text;
int iIndexTipoBusca = cmbTipoBusca.SelectedIndex;

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sVlrBusca))
{
    if (iIndexTipoBusca == 0)
    {
        if (Regex.IsMatch(sVlrBusca.Substring(0, 1), "^[0-9]"))
        {
            dv.RowFilter = "IdxTab = " + sVlrBusca;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Verifique o texto digitado ou tipo de busca.");
        }
    }
    else if (iIndexTipoBusca == 1)
    {
        if (Regex.IsMatch(sVlrBusca.Substring(0, 1), "^[a-zA-Z]"))
        {
            dv.RowFilter = "NomeCampo LIKE '%" + sVlrBusca + "%'";
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Verifique o texto digitado ou tipo de busca.");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (Regex.IsMatch(sVlrBusca.Substring(0, 1), "^[a-zA-Z]"))
        {
            dv.RowFilter = "NomeTab LIKE '%" + sVlrBusca + "%'";
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Verifique o texto digitado ou tipo de busca.");
        }
    }

    if (dv.Count > 0)
    {
        DgvPesquisa.DataSource = dv;
        ConfiguraDgv();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Nenhum valor encontrado.");
    }
}
```

Porem seleciono com ENTER quero transferir o nome do campo q esta na tela de pesquisa para o formulário  esta atrás desse de pesquisa, porem só tenho o nome do campo e não consigo focar dentro do campo q esta na tela atrás dessa tela de pesquisa.

```
private void DgvPesquisa_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        string sNomeCampo = DgvPesquisa.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();

        //((TextBox)FrmPrincipal.GetCampo(sNomeCampo, cCamposTemp)).Focus();
        Close();
    }
}
```

Como essa parte para em cima.

Answer (score 1):

Para passar valores do Form2 para o Form1, você terá que definir qual formulário usando o Application.OpenForms, por exemplo;

```
var frm = (Nome_do_form)Application.OpenForms.Cast<Form>().Where(x => x.Name == "Nome_do_form").FirstOrDefault();
    if (frm != null)
    {
        // com a instancia do formulário (frm) já definida, você irá conseguir passar os valores...
        frm.textBox1.Text = sNomeCampo;
    }
```

*OBS textBox1 deverá ter a propriedade Modifiers com Public*

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-ask).